# bash sum grouping loop

Tags: bash, loops, awk, grouping

i have a helpfile1 of a format:

```
client1 bla blahblah 2542 KB
client1 bla blahblah 4342 MB
client1 bla blahblah    7 GB

client2 bla blahblah  455 MB
client2 bla blahblah  455 MB
```

...

And i need to get weeklysize

```
client1 SUM xy KB
client2 SUM yx KB
```

Currently im using:

```
sumfunction ()
    {
    inputfile=helpfile1

    for i in `awk -F":" '{print $1}' $inputfile| sort -u | xargs`
    do
    awk -v name=$i 'BEGIN {sum=0};
    $0~name {
    print $0;
    if ($5 == "GB") sum = sum + $4*1024*1024;
    if ($5 == "MB") sum = sum + $4*1024;
    if ($5 == "KB") sum = sum + $4};
    END {print name " SUM " sum " kB"}' $inputfile
    done
    }   

sumfunction | grep SUM | sort -g -r -k 3 > weeklysize
```

i need to use it on pretty long file and this awk is taking too much time. Is there another code (bash only), to get this done faster? Thank you

Comment: What about changing the way information is written in `helpfile1`?

Comment: Good code, goodish question, only hampered by lack of your setting expectations. What do you mean 'too much time', 1 sec, 2 mins, 3 hrs, 4 days? for how many "records", (obtained by `wc -l tooBigFile`) AND what sort of hardware are you running this on. While 2X faster be good enough? e Try making a reg ex from your name arg and anchor at the beginning of the line, then you're not scanning the whole line to match what is only at the beginning, ie. `name="^"$1 ; $0~name` OR why  not just `$1=-name { ...` Good luck.

Comment: @shellter Are you sure that you are in the right movie?

Comment: @hek2mgl : Yes I think so, quoting for the O.P. "and this awk is taking too much time". I like your solution, but who knows if OP will, maybe it is too slow. Good luck to all ; -)

Comment: @shellter Ok, got you :) However, my or Adrian's solutions should not take too much time, and no, time is not relative ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following awk script:

```
awk '/MB$/{$4*=1024};/GB$/{$4*=1024*1024};{a[$1]+=$4}END{for(i in a){printf "%s %s KB\n",i, a[i]}}' a.txt
```

Looks better in this format:

```
/MB$/    {$4*=1024};        # handle MB
/GB$/    {$4*=1024*1024};   # handle GB

# count KB amount for the client
{a[$1]+=$4}

END{
    for(i in a){
        printf "%s %s KB\n",i, a[i]
    }
}
```

Output

```
client1 11788782 KB
client2 931840 KB
```

Answer (score 4):

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    output_unit = "KB"
    modifier["KB"] = 1
    modifier["MB"] = 1024
    modifier["GB"] = 1024**2
}
NF  { sums[$1] += modifier[$5] * $4 }
END {
    for (client in sums) {
        printf "%s SUM %d %s\n", client, sums[client]/modifier[output_unit], output_unit
    }
}
```

Notes:

- blank lines will be skipped (`NR { [...] }`)
- the output unit is configurable by setting `output_unit` accordingly (`KB`, `MB`, `GB`)

---

```
$ ./t.awk t.txt
client1 SUM 11788782 KB
client2 SUM 931840 KB
```

Answer (score 3):

Pure Bash (4.0+):

```
declare -Ai client                  # associative array

while read c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 ; do
  if [ -n "$c5" ] ; then
    if [ $c5 = 'KB' ] ; then
      client[$c1]+=$c4
    elif [ $c5 = 'MB' ] ; then
      client[$c1]+=$c4*1024
    elif [ $c5 = 'GB' ] ; then
      client[$c1]+=$c4*1024*1024
    fi
  fi
done < "$infile"

for c in ${!client[@]}; do          # print sorted results
  printf "%s %20d KB\n" $c ${client[$c]}
done | sort  -k1
```

Output

```
client1             11788782 KB
client2               931840 KB
```